Use different citation and bibliography styles in different parts of a document
How can I change the citation and bibliography style in Part B below to a numeric style while retaining the author year in Part A? I have looked at this question Biblatex: Two bibliographies with different styles and sortings similar in general, I notice some differences, like the citations used both sections there are different. In my case I use some of the same citations in both sections, so two separate .bib files may not be needed. Also when I change alphabetic to authoryear style the citations still appear in 4 letters as the former.
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,english]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\graphicspath{
    {../graphics/}
}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue
}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{canadian}{canadian-apa}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}

    \part{Sample header 1} \label{}
    \begin{refsection}
    
    \section{Section One}
    
    \cite{Csir2012}

    \printbibliography
\end{refsection}

\part{Sample header 2} \label{}
    
    \begin{refsection}
        
    \section{section two}
        
    \cite{Johnson2023}
        
    \printbibliography
        
    \end{refsection}
    
\end{document}

refs.bib
    @techreport{Csir2012,
    author = {{Council for Scientific and Industrial Research}},
    title = {{Order of magnitude estimator for new hospitals}},
    year = {2012}
    }
    @article{Johnson2023,
    author = {Johnson, Yasmina and Goldberg, Paul and Moodley, Jennifer and Algar, Ursula and Thomson, Sandie and Sinanovic, Edina and Ramesar, Raj},
    doi = {10.1007/S10552-022-01645-Z/TABLES/4},
    issn = {15737225},
    journal = {Cancer Causes and Control},
    keywords = {Colonoscopy,Colorectal cancer,Cost analysis,Cost-effectiveness,Genetic testing,HNPCC,Lynch Syndrome},
    number = {2},
    pages = {161--169},
    pmid = {36355273},
    publisher = {Springer Science and Business Media Deutschland GmbH},
    title = {{A comparative cost analysis of two screening strategies for colorectal cancer in Lynch Syndrome in a South African tertiary hospital}},
    volume = {34},
    year = {2023}
    }



this is covered quite well in Biblatex's manual also.

you don't need anything as complex as the answers to the question @Marijn linked, though. a far simpler set up is fine for a straightforward switch of style.
